# Unmerge in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, range

I'd like to unmerge all the cells of my google spreadsheet using script. I believe that VBA has this option (cells.unmerge) but I can't find a similar operation in GAS. I've tried this script but it didn't seem to work.

```
function MyFunction() {
var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var Range = Sheet.getDataRange().activate();
Range.clearFormat();
}
```

Comment: See **[this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441604/split-break-apart-merged-table-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-with-an-apps-script)**.

Comment: Unmerge all cells in sheet: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().breakApart();`

Answer (score 1):

The correct word is "Range.breakApart" not "unmerge". Note that this only works when the range it is called on encompasses all merged cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
function unmerge() {
   var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  // get current active sheet use single line coding
  var activeSheet =app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // get last row
  var lstrow= activeSheet.getLastRow();

  // see below description **
  var mergerange = activeSheet.getRange(13,4,lstrow).getMergedRanges();

  for (var i = 0; i < mergerange.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(mergerange[i].getA1Notation());
        Logger.log(mergerange[i].getDisplayValue());
        mergerange[i].breakApart();
   }
}
```

** 13= start row number. 4 = column number of merge cells.

Comment: Great.  Adapted it to loop across all columns as well in the sheet.  Changed the following:
let lastCol = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
for (let column = 1; column < lastCol; column++){
  let mergerange = activeSheet.getRange(1,column,lastrow).getMergedRanges();
  mergerange.map(cells => cells.breakApart())
  }