# Google Script - Function to unmerge cells?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm in the process of automating one of my weekly reports - however part of this process involves the merging of cells and unmerging - currently unmerging is done seperatly however im just wondering if such a method exists to find cells that are merged and unmerge them?

Many thanks.

Comment: Unmerge all cells in sheet: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().breakApart();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAS has a method to unmerge cells but unfortunately there is no way to know which cells are merged.
Some users have suggested a few workarounds, the one I prefer is described in this post:  [Split (break apart) merged table cells in google spreadsheet with an apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441604/split-break-apart-merged-table-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-with-an-apps-script)

There is also an enhancement request and interesting suggestions mentioned in this post:  [How do I know if spreadsheet cells are merged using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025543/how-do-i-know-if-spreadsheet-cells-are-merged-using-google-apps-script/12079460#12079460)

Answer (score 14):

My answer to this question will be "clear formatting" Option in Format menu.

Answer (score -5):

Paste the data in Excel , unmerge all the cells and past it back in google sheets , confirm by wrapping the text in the column where there were Merged cells.

**simple**

1. copy from google sheets
2. Paste in Excel
3. unmerge all the cells in Excel
4. paste in google sheets .

Comment: The questions is regarding how to do it in Google Apps Script, not manually. Btw, you could unmerge them manually in the Spreadsheets as well.